# Google apps-script FinanceApp Error: Service invoked too many times for one day: finance

Tags: google-apps-script

What is the quata limit for FinanceApp.getStockInfo(symbol)? When the service will resume?

Comment: Did you check the Quota limit from Google Dashboard - https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Due to informational use only character of FinanceApp, Google allows only short running scripts (5 minutes each day). 
You should be able to run your script again after 24 hours

Found it on google here:
https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=157#hc7

Some useful information about terms of using this App can be also found here:
http://www.google.com/googlefinance/disclaimer#disclaimers