# Google finance for app script not shown in Google dashboard

Tags: google-apps-script, quota, google-finance

I wonder how I can check the remaining quota if I run a script which make calls to FinanceApp. As many other Google services, Google has set some restrictions for Finance service and I can't continue to test my script if it has reached its daily quota.

I've checked on my Google dashboard but there's no information about Finance service at all.
Anyone knows if there's a method similar to `MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()` for FinanceApp?

Answer (score 0):

first result in a search for "finance" on this forum with `[google-apps-script]` tag ...

[Google apps-script FinanceApp Error: Service invoked too many times for one day: finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878151/google-apps-script-financeapp-error-service-invoked-too-many-times-for-one-day)

and there are a few others.

Comment: Yes I've read it before my last post, but looking at the quota limits in the dashboard page shows "Trigger Aggregate Execution Time 1 hours / day". My script takes less then 3 seconds to run, and even if it's triggered every minute for 8 hours a day, the aggregate execution time is 24 minutes per day, so totally below 1 hour. If I have no way to check how much quota my script has used, I guess it's better to change it and adopt other data feed services such as Yahoo